# Is it alright to put sensitive data into the cache? ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I currently implemented some "checkers" for my MVC application.

So far here is what i have,

1. Authorization(Form)
2. Authentication (Custom RoleProvider)
3. Action Filters(to make sure that the user won't put any bogus id numbers or try accessing the other's data by editing the `GET` url.

I have several questions regarding the best practices for `cache` on ASP MVC.

Here is my implementation of my login:

```
  [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("login")]
    public ActionResult login_load()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("login")]
    public ActionResult login_post(string uname,string pword)
    {

        using (EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext())
        {
           //h student log = new student();
            int success = emp.login.Where(x => x.username == uname && x.password == pword).Count();
            if (success == 1)
            {
                int id = (from logs in emp.login
                          join rol in emp.roles on logs.role equals rol.id
                          where logs.username == uname
                          select logs.id).First();

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(uname, false);
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("id", id);
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Enrollment", new { id = id});
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

(I plan on implementing H&S as soon)

Anyway, here are my concerns so far:

1. For security concerns, would it be fine to store something like `id`'s on cache? or it's better if i use `sessions` ?
2. Let's say i successfully logged in, and i add another line of this code :

   `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("id", id);`

   Is it going to edit my previous record or it's going to add another entry?
   I have this code from my Custom `RoleProvider`, `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, roles, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_cacheTimeoutInMinute), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);` and i believe that they are "fired" everytime i ask a controller with a protection of `[Authorize(Role="users")]`. So does it make a new entry or it edits the previous/existing one?
3. Should i worry about deleting/clearing my `cache` as soon as the user decided to log out? my role provider timeout is currently set to `20 minutes`

I need the `id` because aside from the username, it is my unique identifier and i use it to compare on whatever id the user is trying to access.

I am thinking if it would be possible to edit the cache and use it against my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For security concerns, would it be fine to store something like id's on cache? or it's better if i use sessions ?

In this case it doesn't make a lot of difference. However, the cache cannot be distributed across multiple web servers. Session state can by changing the `<sessionState>` section of the `web.config` file. So you are building an inherent limitation in scalability into your application by using cache.

> Let's say i successfully logged in, and i add another line of this code :
>
> `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("id", id);`
>
> Is it going to edit my previous record or it's going to add another entry? I have this code from my Custom RoleProvider, HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, roles, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_cacheTimeoutInMinute), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration); and i believe that they are "fired" everytime i ask a controller with a protection of [Authorize(Role="users")]. So does it make a new entry or it edits the previous/existing one?

First of all, you have a major flaw in your code. Cache is intended to be ***shared between all users on the site.*** So, when you insert a value, such as `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("id", id);`, all of the users will see it. If you are using this value to lookup data later, then the user data will always be for the last user that signed in.

You can fix this by adding adding a value unique to the user to the key.

```
var key = this.User.Identity.Name + "|Id";
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, id);
```

Note I am using a pipe character as a separator here. This is assuming the user name doesn't allow a pipe character (which you would also need to ensure).

Secondly, using a proper cache pattern means that you will never need to worry about whether "id" exists because you have already made that check. Using the cache typically looks like this.

```
public static string GetUserID()
{
    // Check whether the user is logged in
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Make a UNIQUE key that can be used for this scenario
    var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    var key = userName + "|Id";

    // Attempt to get the ID from the cache
    var id = HttpRuntime.Cache[key];

    // A null value indicates there was no value in the cache
    if (id == null)
    {
        // No ID in the cache, look it up from the database
        using (EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext())
        {
            id = (from user in emp.login
                where user.username = userName
                select user.id).First();
        }
    
        // Store the ID from the database into the cache
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, id, 
        
            // No Dependencies
            null, 
            
            // No absolute expiration (mimic the behavior of forms authentication)
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
            
            // Timeout 20 minutes after the last access 
            // (to mimic the behavior of forms authentication)
            new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0),

            // Setting to NotRemovable ensures that if the
            // application pool restarts, you don't lose your cache
            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, 

            // No callback needed here
            null);
    }

    return (string)id
}
```

Of course, you can improve performance if the value is available at login by inserting it into the cache directly, but you need to ensure you use the same key in that case.

Session is probably a better choice in this scenario, but either way you should make use of this pattern to double check you have a value before returning it to the user.

> Should i worry about deleting/clearing my cache as soon as the user decided to log out? my role provider timeout is currently set to 20 minutes

If you use Session state instead of cache this is much easier. Simply call `Session.Abandon()` when the user logs out.

Comment: Finally, i need an answer like this. Thank you :D

Comment: Wait so i should use sessions? and anyway `var key = this.User.Identity.Name + "|Id";` can you explain to me what is `Identity`? is this from the `Identity framework` ?

Comment: No, this is part of forms authentication. There are generic interfaces, `IUser` and `IIdentity` that any security mechanism can implement to customize where the user profile data is stored or add other custom behavior that is specific to the security framework/scheme that is used.

Comment: Alright thank you so much :D didn't know that cache is shared across the site. lastly, what's the proper web config for `sessionState` if i want to implement something like that? i might try it tomorrow.

Comment: The "proper" use of session depends on your application. But it is best to store it out of process by using StateServer or SqlServer. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: Alright, thank you so much. You helped me alot and uhh one more thing: you stated that `the cache cannot be distributed across multiple web servers`, what does this mean and why is this important with regards on my example?

Comment: Its important if you want your web server to be able to scale out to multiple web servers. Using an out-of-process session state option allows you to use a server (or servers) specifically to store session data so if the user's requests don't end up at the same web server their session will still be available. Of course, the best option is to not use state. In the specific scenario you posted, you could easily change your queries to use UserName instead of UserId so you can make it stateless, but then there may be another compelling reason to use state that you haven't posted.

Comment: I red lines from this code btw `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;` edit: nvm oh my how come it appears on some pages and it doesnt on some. same goes w/ this.current

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry about storing the ID, you need to go back and refactor to use the inbuilt identity stuff that's in the box for MVC. Looking at your code I can only assume that this system would store passwords in plain text. You will not pass any compliance with a system like this.

Rule of thumb when it comes to "is this secure" is don't write it yourself. Find a proven product and use that.

If for whatever reason the inbuilt identity system that is provided with MVC doesn't work for your requirements, have a look into this: https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot

FYI:
Identity system is the service that logs people in, out and manages the logged in user. Feel free to head over to this to learn more about the inbuilt system for MVC: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Yeah it's plain text as of now for testing purposes. I will probably hash it sooner or later. but alright i will check it out. is Role Provider and FormAuthentication not enough?

Comment: Please just trust me, you will have to throw everything auth based away that you write sooner or later. Crypto is not a field you can dabble in, it requires many years of expertise. I am fairly clued up when it comes to crypto and I wouldn't even joke about trying to roll my own crypto.

Please just go and learn the way MVC does it by default, it means all that codes already written AND it's proven in production running systems!

Comment: Alright thank you. is it `custom user principal and identity` ?

Comment: I had a quick look at your profile, looks like you are a C++ dev mingling in some C#. I would HIGHLY recomend getting a trial of pluralsight (or just buy a sub, it's amazing) and do the following courses: -- C# fundamentals: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/csharp-fundamentals-csharp5 -- Building Applications with ASP.NET MVC4 http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvc4-building -- ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals

Comment: What do you mean by custom user principal and identity?

Comment: There are other free tutorials out there, but you gotta choose, do I value my time or my wallet. If you can afford it, get it. I'm lucky in that my employer pays for mine, but If I ever left I would get it myself.